# Error with numbers when loading CSV into BigQuery

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am loading a table into BigQuery from Cloud Storage. It's a CSV file, and my code is as follows:

```
LOAD DATA OVERWRITE `cmpc-cl-data-centric-dev.mydataset.BI_STOCK`
FROM FILES (
  format = 'CSV',
  field_Delimiter = ';',
  uris = ['gs://mybucket-bastianrivera/Stock.csv']);
```

The problem I have is with the numbers. For example, a number that is 20,35 in the CSV file gets loaded into the BigQuery table as 20.350, which is incorrect. Is there any way to specify in the query to correctly interpret the numbers?

Comment: Why is it incorrect? 20,35 is the Latin representation. 20.35 is the UTF representation. The meaning is the same at the end.